# How do I remove the dotted line on my image button when I click it in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, dotted-line

I'm using this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KUU95/).  In chrome when I click the image it doesn't produce a dotted line but when I click the image in firefox a dotted line appears.

[image].

How can I remove the dotted line?

I've tried:

```
#myButton:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

#myButton:active {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: Don't see it on my firefox

Comment: The border is there because the image is selected.  To get rid of it, select something else.

Comment: I can only see it when I tab-focus it.

Comment: @nix ... I never want the the user to see it when the click the image.

Comment: @imbondbaby I'm using firefox version 26.0

Comment: Firefox 26 is pretty old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border:0;
}
```

`button` can be replaced with whatever selector for which you want to disable the behavior.

**P.S:** It also works without a selector by just using `::-moz-focus-inner`.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KUU95/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

[Here is updated jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/KUU95/5/)

Basically you want to blur it onfocus with javascript. If using jquery:

```
$(function() {
    var button = $("#myButton");
    $(button).focus(function() { 
        $(this).blur();
    }); 
});
```

Or without jquery something like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
button.onfocus = function() { button.blur(); }
```

With my test on Firefox on Ubuntu, original jfiddle produced dotted line, updated does not.